# Split CALayer into sublayers for animation

Tags: core-animation

I want to create an animation effect similar to the new Lion Mail.app conversation animation shown in the WWDC2011 Keynote.

http://www.razorianfly.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen-shot-2011-02-28-at-16.31.48.png

I have a prototype effect working when using 10 CALayers with static content (UIImageViews) But I need to know how to do this at runtime.

How do I take a layer hierarchy and split it into temporary sublayers to animate?

Comment: Could this be achieved with CAReplicatorLayer?

Answer (score 0):

What I do for something very similar on iOS is to create an offscreen bitmap context, render my layer into that using the CALayer call renderInContext, and then slice and dice the resulting image into a bunch of separate CGImages using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(). I then install each image as the content of a layer it works quite well.

The Bill Dudney Core Animation book has a sample iOS app called Confetti that shows how to do the slicing and dicing.

It would be a little more work in Mac OS because you don't have the very convenient UIGraphicsBeginImageContext method, and will have to use low-level CG calls to create an offscreen context, but it's documented in the Xcode docs on Quartz in a section titled "Graphics Contexts".